# SDL with classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

Hello am having a problem with my IDE Visual Studio 2012. I have started to learn SDL so am quite new to it and I am trying apply good structure when using SDL. The problems lays when I start using SDL with classes. It works fine if I type everything in main. I don't know what am doing wrong can you help here are the errors

```
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in LIBCMT.lib (crt0dat.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in LIBCMT.lib(_file.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) : error LNK2005: _fclose already defined in LIBCMT.lib(fclose.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Nebula\Debug\Nebula.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is my code if there is something wrong

Main

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "System.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    System RedObject;
    RedObject.SetUp();

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Second file.

```
#include "System.h"

System::System()
{
}

System::~System()
{
}

void System::SetUp()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING); // The SDL Set up bit.
    SDL_Surface * screen;
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Window Name", NULL);

    fullscreen = false;

    if(fullscreen == true)
    {
        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    }

    bool running = true;

    while(running)
    {
        SDL_Event Event;

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
        {
            switch(Event.type)

                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                break;
        }

        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }
}
```

Second Files Header:

```
#ifndef SYSTEM_H
#define SYSTEM_H

#include <SDL.h>

class System
{
    private:
        int SHeight, SLenght;
        bool fullscreen;

    public:
        System();
        ~System();
        void SetUp();
};

#endif
```

Also I have set up the IDE code generator to run on Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) I don't know if that is the problem. Sorry if this question has been already answered I could find an answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like SDL was compiled against a different CRT than the one you're using (/MD). Does SDL have a /MD version? Is it using the debug CRT (/MDd)? Welcome to the joy of C++ ABI woes, by the way :-)

Comment: @Cameron: I think you should say "the joy of MS DLL linking". The affected libraries have actually little to do with C++ ABIs - they are mostly C

Comment: Am not sure. I set SDL how would I find out what version it is? Thanks I have had these errors before but this time am really stuffed.

Comment: Does your switch statement really have no braces { } ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor: Good catch! Actually the `break` statement is breaking the `while` becase the `switch` has only one one statement.

Comment: You could compile SDL yourself with the /MD option. SDL 2.0 is still in construction but I never had any problems and a MSVC project is already provided on the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! This problem come up when you build objects with SDL and there are conflicts of two lib's you need to ignore one of them. You need to ignore LIBCMT.lib. If you don't know how to here are the steps:

1. Open the project's Property Pages.
2. Click the Linker folder.
3. Click the Input page.
4. Select the Ignore Specific Default Libraries and go into the edit and put in LIBCMT.lib press ok then apply setting and you should be good to go.

I hope this saves you days of pain :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Visual Studio's .NET Framework uses `System` as a root-level namespace, so you're probably running into a name conflict.  Try naming your class something other than System.

Comment: He's not using .NET, though.

Comment: Cameron, perhaps he's not *trying* to use .NET, but depending on how the Visual Studio project was created it may still be included in the build.  That being said, he found a totally unrelated solution, so I suppose this was not the issue.